# It's necessary to remove views? In order to cleanup the Alloy controller (memory/performance)

Tags: memory, appcelerator, code-cleanup

Lets say that I've a ScrollableView with 3 Views (forms), those form views have at least 10 fields, take a look at this exemple.

index.js

```
$.content.add(Alloy.createController('scrollable').getView());
```

scrollable.js

```
$.scrollableView.addView(Alloy.createController('form',{
    fields:[
        {label:'field 1',type:'text'},
        {label:'field 1',type:'date',value:'2016-06-08'},
        ...
    ]
}).getView());

$.scrollableView.cleanup = function() {

    $.destroy();

    $.off();

    for(var i = parseInt($.scrollableView.views.length); i > 0; i--) if($.scrollableView.views[i-1]) {

        if($.scrollableView.views[i-1].cleanup) $.scrollableView.views[i-1].cleanup();
        $.scrollableView.views[i-1] = null;
        $.scrollableView.removeView($.scrollableView.views[i-1]);
    }   

    $ = args = null;
};
```

form.js

```
for(var i in args.fields) $.form.add(Alloy.createController('field',args.fields[i]).getView());

$.form.cleanup = function() {

    $.destroy();

    $.off();

    for(var i in $.form.children) {

        if($.form.children[i].cleanup) $.form.children[i].cleanup();
        $.form.children[i] = null;
    }

    $.form.removeAllChildren();

    $ = args = null;
};
```

When I'm cleaning up all the controllers, I still don't understand what it's necessary to do.

When I want to remove the ScrollableView, I run the cleanup function on every View, and it's children.

- Should I run the cleanup function on all the ScrollableView views?
- Should I null all the ScrollableView views?
- Should I remove all the ScrollableView views?
- Should I run the cleanup function on all the View children?
- Should I null all the View children?
- Should I remove all the View children?

**UPDATE**

In this case, I still need to cleanup all the fields? or setting the data to null will solve that?

form.js

```
var args = arguments[0],
    data = {
        fields:{}
    };

for(var i in args.fields) {

    data.fields[args.fields[i].label] = Alloy.createController('field',args.fields[i]).getView();

    $.form.add(data.fields[args.fields[i].label]);
}

$.form.cleanup = function() {

    $.destroy();

    $.off();

    //this is needed?
    for(var i in data.fields) {

        if(data.fields[i].cleanup) data.fields[i].cleanup();
        data.fields[i] = null;
    }
    //this is needed?

    $ = data = args = null;
};
```

Anyway, if my fields have an event listener added like 'change' or 'click', I must remove it in cleanup function, right?

Comment: If you `null` the data, all references to the different views will be lost too. So that will fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to remove all views, the only thing you need to do to clean up memory is remove the most parent view, and all references to anything within the most parent view & the reference to the parent view.

So in your case, you only have to remove the ScrollableView and within the scrollableview you need to do `$.off()`. `$.destroy()` is only needed if you use data-binding (models/collections).

Because your child views never have a reference (variable), there is no need to remove them. It is automatically handled by Appcelerator/JavaScript and will be cleaned up with garbage collection when the time comes.

note: Garbage collection doesn't happen directly after you remove the views, so you might still have increased memory usage. Both JavaScript and the native platform have their own garbage collection.

You can read more about memory management in this [article on TiDev](http://www.tidev.io/2014/03/27/memory-management/) which is still very relevant.

In your updated question you set all the sub-views in the `data` object. `null`ing the data object will also drop all references to the views, so that should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I don't use models or collections, so isn't necessary $.destroy and $.off? I thought that it was always necessary, http://www.tidev.io/2014/09/18/cleaning-up-alloy-controllers/

Comment: Just one more thing, If I reference the form, and it's fields, I need to set them as null in my cleanup function, right?

Comment: You only need to use `$.off` Only `$.destroy()` is for data binding. And if you have references to all children of the form, you need to `null` them all.

Comment: Lets say that in my form view I have a variable called data = {}; and when I'm building the form, I add all the fields to data.fields = {}; on my form cleanup function, I don't need to loop in data.fields, I can set only the data to null?

Comment: I'm using SQLite querys and pass it to the views as arguments, for this, I still don't need off and destroy?

Comment: you ALWAYS need `$.off()`. You ONLY need `$.destroy()` when you use data-binding. SQLite doesn't count as data-binding. This is data binding: https://medium.com/all-titanium/enhancing-titanium-how-to-set-up-collections-with-databinding-39573cd30911#.xsd7obwhq

Comment: I've been doing some tests, if I just remove and null the parent view, my child view has 2 variables (data & args), that variables will remain? In one of my child views, I've a alert dialog that shows a property of data object, the timeout has 60 seconds, I've removed and nulled the parent view, but still, after some seconds, when the alerts shows up, the data.test value still exists, but if I run a cleanup method in all childrens, the alert can't find the variable

Comment: Because you have a timeout there, the entire controller cannot be cleaned up, because you still need it. Even if you clean up yourself, the controller itself still exists. If you drop all references to that view and the view has nothing to do anymore it can be cleaned up by garbage collection. When exactly this happens depends on the OS.