# Passing arguments, self invoked functions and widgets or controllers

Tags: function, arguments, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

What is the best approach for the Alloy controllers? What's the difference? data variable will never 'get out' of the controller:

```
var args = arguments[0] || {},
    data = {};

data.title = args.name+', '+args.age;

console.log(data.title);
```

or

```
var data = {};

(function(args){

    data.title = args.name+', '+args.age;

    console.log(data.title);

}),arguments[0] || {});
```

Other thing, I'm using elements in my all controllers (buttons, forms, tables, etc..) actually, these elements are widgets, should they be simple controllers? there is any disadvantage of use widgets instead of a simple controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a controller there is no need to use a self executing function, the only reason there possibly can be is personal preference.

Your second question about elements is also personal preference. But since Widgets require you to set up a `widget.json` and include it in the `config` it has slight overhead. Not in terms of performance. You could just as well use a regular controller. Again, question of preference.

However, I do usually have this rule for myself: Wigets are things you want to use in other apps / open source. Controllers are 1-app only.

Comment: Thanks again Rene Pot, I don't know if you saw my comment in your question, about nulling object properties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696616/its-necessary-to-remove-views-in-order-to-cleanup-the-alloy-controller-memory#comment62870263_37697052

Comment: It was the object comment, I've updated the main question, could your check it out please? (marked as update in bold)